# rails_blob_path host: and only_path: true returns the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Im trying to figure out how to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path`

I have an class with

```
has_one_attached :logo
```

and then I do

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(record.logo)
```

It gives me an error

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true (ArgumentError)
```

Ok so I try

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(obi.logo, host: "wwww.example.com" )
=> "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5d977f0c66fecd8c8474355813aad9490fcdfbf2/picture.png"
```

Which is the same outcome as

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(obi.logo, only_path: true )
=> "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5d977f0c66fecd8c8474355813aad9490fcdfbf2/picture.png"
```

When using the `host:` parameter I would expect it to attach "www.example.com" to the output. Why is it the same outcome as `only_path: true` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using the host: parameter I would expect it to attach "www.example.com" to the output. Why is it the same outcome as only_path: true ?

In Rails there are two types of URL-helpers -- `path` and `url`

With suffix `_path` -- relative URL path

With suffix `_url` -- absolute URL

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(obi.logo, host: "https://www.example.com")

# => "https://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5d977f0c66fecd8c8474355813aad9490fcdfbf2/picture.png"
```